# Service worker do not serve cached resources

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

Although I see similar questions regarding the subject, there are not the same. So, I have a pwa app that is basically a simple form that users must fill out. The service worker catch the resources and serves to the app, as usual. The strategy is 'cache first, then network'. All is ok, when is onLine, BUT in offLine mode, the cached resources are not used by the app, I mean, in spite that (you can see) in the cache are the resources(fetch requests) that the app needs, it anyway try to fetch to the web and obviously because there is offLine, the fetch fail and the app crash. So, the code lines ...

```
caches.match(e.request)
    .then( res => {
        if (res ){
            return res;
        }
```

...
is not working. My question....Why???.
I will appreciate you help/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some more context and code, to let others better understand your situation.

Do you serve data from the cache like the following example?

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: hi Francesco, thank for your answer...Yes, my sw is pretty the same as your. My point is :,,, when all the resources are catched, (you can see then in the cache) 'theoretically' I should be able to work offLine, because all the request are cached, well it is not true, the data is there BUT (I do not know why) the app still fetch to the web as it is not in the cache, and obviously because is offLine, the fetch failed and the app crash.

Comment: You can put some breakpoints (or console.logs) to see if your `caches.open` method correctly opens the local cache. If this is the case, you can proof that the parameter of the `match()` method is what you would expect. Maybe there is a small typo or difference in the request and therefore the CACHE API does not return a successful match. Without seeing the whole code or, even better, a Stackbliz example it is hard to help further

Comment: Hi, yes , I am working on that, it seems to me also that there is a bad typo o something similar...I will write later the results... thank again for your help.